# Restrict access to resource based on grant type in addition to scope

Tags: oauth-2.0

From my understanding: -

- The scopes that an oauth client can obtain are registered against the client on the Authorization Server .
- The grant types that a client can use are registered against the client on the Authorization Server .
- Resources are configured to allow requests containing access tokens that are associated with certain scopes.

Is there a mechanism in vanilla OAuth where the grant type in addition to the scopes are used when restricting an endpoint?

For example, given Client A with scopes=organizations, images and grant types=client credentials, auth code:

(at token creation)

- For Client A to obtain an access token for ‘organizations’ scope, only client credentials grant type can be used.
- For Client A to obtain an access token for ‘images’ scope, only auth code grant type can be used.

Or (when the resource endpoint it calls)

- When the /organisation endpoint is called with an access token containing the expected ‘organization’ scope, only allow the request if the client credentials grant type was used to obtain the access token (fail if any other grant type was used).
- When the /images endpoint is called with an access token for containing the expected ‘images’ scope, only allow the request if the auth code grant type was used to obtain the access token (fail if any other grant type was used).

As far as I know scopes are only limited by what is registered for a client.

The only way I can think of achieving the above would be to have two client registrations (e.g. b, c) for the same actual client (A) and configure client ‘b’ for client credentials grant type and organizations scope and client ‘c’ for auth code grant type and images scope.

**Update**

One option would be along OIDC lines to add a roles scope which would mean that the roles claims would be added to the access token. The access token could then be inspected to see whether the role is a third party (client credentials grant) or user (auth code grant). 
I would still be interested to know if there is anything specifically built into oauth to restrict by grant type.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens don't generally record grant information, and really the requirement is to be able to control access per application and based on the caller's rights.

I would always configure different OAuth Clients for different grant types - since these are different logical clients and can never share a session.

A few possible options:

- OPTION 1. Use multiple APIs each with a [different audience](https://hanszandbelt.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/the-importance-of-audience-in-web-sso/amp/) and configure different audiences for different OAuth Clients if that is supported by your Authorization Server
- OPTION 2. An API endpoint can potentially check the client ID in access tokens against a list of allowed client IDs - though this is not a good long term option
- OPTION 3. Use OAuth just to identify the caller and then look up rights for the caller that are stored and managed in your application data. This is almost always the best long term option.

OAuth only provides high level mechanisms for authorization and when you get into deeper domain specific authorization (eg what a role means or rules such as checking sufficient funds) it will not help you.

I like your idea of using roles, and from experience I would manage them like this:

- Do high level OAuth authorization first via scopes etc
- Identify the caller from the token's claims
- Look up the caller's role(s) in your application data
- Enforce the role's authorization rules in your API logic

Comment: Thanks, confirms what I was thinking.